# Syntax for DML update

Tags: apex, soql

I am working on a cleanup of our EmailTemplate structure. Moving a lot of templates between various folders. What is syntax in Apex for the equivalent of this SQL...

Update EmailTemplate set FolderID=(some ID) where ID IN ('id1', 'id2', 'id3' etc...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you already have the Id values you can do this:

```
Set<Id> ids = new Set<Id>{'..', '...', ...};
Id someId = ...;

EmailTemplate[] templates = new EmailTemplate[] {};
for (Id id : ids) {
    templates.add(new EmailTemplate(Id = id, FolderId = someId));
}
update templates;
```